# Corner Radius of View in UITableViewCell Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, frame, cornerradius

I am trying to create a round view in my tablevviewcell subclass

i set the cornerRadius to half the width, but the frame is returning 0. so corner radius is not setting correctly.

```
initialView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0), excludingEdge: .trailing)
    initialView.autoMatch(.width, to: .height, of: initialView)
    initialView.layer.cornerRadius = initialView.frame.size.width/2
```

Thanks

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    initialView.layer.cornerRadius = initialView.frame.size.width/2
    print(initialView.frame)

}
```

Frame is still printing -> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.addSubview(initialView)
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    setupConstraints()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    initialView.layer.cornerRadius = initialView.frame.size.width/2
    print(initialView.frame)

}
```

Comment: what is `initialView`?

Comment: it is just a UIView

Comment: private(set) lazy var initialView: UIView = {
        let initialView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        return initialView
    }()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to fix this is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and put your code into `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    initialView.layer.cornerRadius = initialView.frame.size.width/2
}
```

And put the rest of the code in your question in your `init()` code:

```
func init() {
    // other stuff...

    setupInitialView()
}

func setupInitialView() {
    initialView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0), excludingEdge: .trailing)
    initialView.autoMatch(.width, to: .height, of: initialView)
}
```

---

My complete (working!) `UITableViewCell` class is as follows. Instead of using the `PureLayout` pod I used an extension method that basically does the same thing.

```
//
//  MyTableViewCell.swift
//  tableviewheader-test
//
//  Created by Forest Kunecke on 3/31/17.
//  Free as in free beer!
//

import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private(set) lazy var initialView: UIView = {
        let initialView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        return initialView
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        //
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(initialView)

        setupInitialView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setupInitialView() {
        self.contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-5-[v0]-5-|", views: initialView)
        self.contentView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-5-[v0]-0-|", views: initialView)

        initialView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.initialView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot (with the `UITableViewController` returning `view.frame.width` for `heightForRowAt`):

[image]

If you want I can also post the `UITableViewController` I used to test this code.

Comment: do you need to call cell.layoutIfNeeded()? from the ViewController Class?

Comment: That probably won't fix your issue, because the problem is the value that is actually set into the views frame is based on the view as a nib instead of the view initialized in your tableView.

Comment: Not using storyboards or nibs. All set programmatically.

Comment: Just added more code to original question. My setup code is in the override init function

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the interaction before the view is laid out. You need to subclass the UITableViewCell and override `layoutSubviews` like so:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        initialView.layer.cornerRadius = initialView.frame.size.width/2
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to call cell.layoutIfNeeded()? from the ViewController Class? Still not working. I am printing the frame in the layoutSubviews() still printing 0.0)